Access internal API inside AWS VPC
I have two AWS EC2 instances in the same VPC, Region, and Subnet. On instance A I have a very simple Web API setup in IIS on say port 12345. What I would like to do is have instance B be able to access the Web API on instance A without leaving the VPC. I have tried to access the API from instance B using the private IP (10.0.x.x:12345/api/) but it doesn't work. Both servers are part of the same Security Group as well, and I have a rule allowing all traffic on all ports for the source 10.0.0.0/16. I know I am missing something, just not quite sure what. Any help or pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Being in the same security group doesn't allow things to automatically access each other. But the rule allowing all traffic, being applied to the security group they are both in, should be allowing the traffic. As long as you are using the private IP then it should be working. Is there perhaps some soft of firewall software running on instance A?

Thank you @MarkB that was exactly it. Since I am using a non-standard port in IIS I needed to open the port through the Windows Firewall.

Answered in the comment above, copying here as well: "Since I am using a non-standard port in IIS I needed to open the port through the Windows Firewall."
